# Visual Studio F# Intellisense stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, f#

VS Pro F# compiler still works.  Correct F# code still runs.  *BUT hovering over a function or symbol in a VS window presenting F# code no longer causes its type to appear as a tool-tip.*

For no reason I can discern my Visual Studio Pro has stopped live-checking my F# code.  No idea why the change.  I can still compile and of course type errors are still emitted.

- Any idea where it is controlled in VS Pro?
- Any ideas why F# Intellisense might suddenly NOT
  work in VS Pro?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work on a new F# projects? This kind of thing may happen if there is something wrong with your project setup - e.g. wrong references or framework version.

Comment: I’ve had the same issue with recent releases of Visual Studio. No Intellisense. The only thing that fixes it is restarting VS.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Even opening the Elmish.WPF/src/Samples/NewWindow project results in no syntax highlighting *until I build*.  After a successful project build the F# code shows the Type tooltips.  The development project is yet to successfully build so I think you are right.

Comment: @BrianBerns I have restarted a number of times to no effect.  I think Tomas Petricek might have the right idea.

Comment: @BrianBerns Hmmm...when I restart VS and then Build->Clean followed by Build->Rebuild the Type tooltips reappear.  So you may also be correct.

Comment: I brought this up in F# Slack, and we were told they're working on a fix.

Comment: You have to use the workaround in here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12982#issuecomment-1158903384

Answer (score 1):

*This issue may reappear in the future so I will not mark any answer as final.  If you have a fix that works then please state the version of **Visual Studio** and **F# Tools** (found in the About Visual Studio pop-up) with your answer*

Version:

- Visual Studio 17.23
- Visual F# Tools 17.1.0-beta.2253.3

As Bent Tranberg noted the F# Github repo has a discussion "[F# intellisense sometimes stops working #12982](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12982)".  Looks like a fix will be pushed into the next update of F# (Visual Studio).

But what worked for me was to both:

- close and restart Visual Studio
- Recompile your project (need not be error-free)

After this my Intellisense tooltips would appear.